# Attributes "draggable" and "resizable" don't working on JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm use this code for open dialog window using jquery dialog:

```
       var page = "{{env('APP_URL')}}/reports/dep33";
       var $dialog = $('<div style="overflow:hidden"></div>')
                                    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '?id=' + gr + '" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>')
                                    .dialog({
                                        dialogClass: "no-close",
                                        autoOpen: false,
                                        modal: true,
                                        height: 400,
                                        width: "40%",
                                        draggable: true,
                                        resizable: true
                                        buttons: [{
                                text: "Close",
                                click: function () {
                                $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}]);
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                          }
                                         },
                                       ],
                                        title: "Fast Report",

                                    });
                            $dialog.dialog('open');
```

Attributes like Width,Height, Modal working fine, but attributes draggable and resizable don't working. Why?
The console does not show any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are including the correct css. I had this problem with regard to the resizable behaviour and it was a case of our project was selectively including the different css files and the resizable.css file wasn't included at first.